# Entra Role - Azure DevOps Administrator

Tags: azure-devops, azure-active-directory, azure-devops-services, microsoft-entra-id

am having Azure Active Directory (Entra ID) and and AzureDevOps organization.

In my Azure DevOps organization, there can be only a single user assigned to the role as "Organization Owner":
[image]

How can die EntraRole "Azure DevOps Administrator" be used in order to grant more users the possibility, to act as "Azure DevOps Organization Owner"?

(Otherwise there's a single person doing all the stuff from an organization owner)

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Refer to this doc: [Create and configure organization FAQs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/organizations/accounts/faq-configure-customize-organization?view=azure-devops#q-how-many-organization-owners-can-i-have)

> Q: How many organization Owners can I have?
> A: Your organization can have only one owner. Only organization Owners can do certain actions, so make sure you keep your organization Owner updated.

You cannot have multiple owners for the Azure DevOps Organization.

The role: **Azure DevOps Administrator** in AAD is different from the Organization Owner in Azure DevOps organization. It will have no full access to manage the Organization.

I suggest that you can add the users to **Project Collection Administrators group** in **Organization Settings -> Permissions**. Then the users will have the same access as Organization Owner in Azure DevOps Organization(expcet for recovering a deleted organization).